# Does working in finance firms improve a person's finance knowledge?

Tags: banking, trading, investing, budget

I would like to know whether it is possible to gain personal finance knowledge if a person works in a good finance firm where he comes across many financial models.

Comment: `financial models` - Related to what ? Risk management, trading etc. In current state the question is too broad.

Comment: Depends on what work the person does. I am a software developer in a credit union and have learned a lot of financial stuff, because the code I write has to follow the company's financial rules. But I can think of other people who work here that don't have as much involvement with that type of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what you mean by financial knowledge.  Often you will work in a group focused on some aspect of the company's business.  As an example, I work for a company and my group works on econometric models.  Although I have a degree in finance, I don't encounter or talk about corporate or personal finance.  I do talk about investing with a friend, but in general, our group is focused on one aspect of finance and economics for the company.

From another direction, often financial companies will offer financial literacy training through HR and benefits programs where you can improve your knowledge of finance outside of your groups focus.

In the end, you will learn the most by persuing new knowledge through reading on current financial literature.  I hope this helps.

Edit:  If you add some specifics to what you would like to learn about I may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed information. I wanted to know about whether can i gain personal finance knowledge by working on these firms.

Comment: It is unlikely you would gain knowledge of personal finance in most finance jobs today.  For a solid core of basic knowledge I would recommend something like The Wallstreet Journal Guide to Personal Finance and a subscription to a magaxine such as Money.  If you are interested in budgeting I would take the time sitting ata bookstore and looking through the personal finance section at budgeting books before buying.  Budgeting is a continual growth effort.  You will have to plan, track and readjust your plan.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what work you're doing. If you aren't doing a job which involves working with and understanding the data, probably not.